# Gson error "declares multiple JSON fields named" for overridden inherited fields

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I have 2 classes:

**Parent**

```
class Parent {
    @SerializedName("variable1")
    int variable1;

    @SerializedName("child")
    Child child;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child {
    @SerializedName("childVar")
    int childVar1;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Those are extended like:

**ExtendedChild**

```
class ExtendedChild extends Child {
    @SerializedName("childVar2")
    int childVar2;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**ExtendedParent**

```
class ExtendedParent extends Parent {
    @SerializedName("variable2")
    int variable2; 

    @SerializedName("child")
    ExtendedChild extendedChild;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I want to use these classes for un marshaling from Json. I am planning to use GSON library. I want to un marshal either to ExtendedParent or Parent classes based on the payload. I know in my code which type of Parent it is. Just to represent properly and to avoid redundant variable declaration, I wanted to go with Inheritance. Below are two examples I have with me-

I will marshal the below payload to ExtendedParent.class

```
{
    'variable1':12,
    'variable2':23,
    'child':{
        'childVar1': 43,
        'childVar2': 23
    }
}
```

I will marshal the below payload to Parent.class

```
{
    'variable1':12,
    'child':{
        'childVar1': 43
    }
}
```

However, when I try to to un marshal as below-,

```
ExtendedParent extendedParent = new Gson()
        .fromJson('<Passing the first Json string above>', ExtendedParent.class);
```

I face below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class ExtendedParent declares
>   multiple JSON fields named child

Not able to figure out what is the issue. Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated. I tried several ways to avoid variable hiding on the Child objects but I am not able to figure it out on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

GSON does not cope with fields declared multiple times having the same name whether it was the Java fieldname  or serialize name. Use generics to avoid  this kind of situation. Declare your `Parent` like:

```
public class Parent<T extends Child> {
    private T child;
    // any other stuff
}
```

and `ExtendedParent` like:

```
public class ExtendedParent extends Parent<ExtendedChild> {
    // note no more declaring the field "child"
    // any other stuff
}
```

If you need to use name `extendedChild` you can just create getters & setters for that name that handle with `child`.

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33345170/6413377).

Comment: Awesome, that did work. Thank you for your insight. This solution is quick and neat.