# Error: "declares multiple JSON fields named..." when parsing classes with getter/setter values defined in interfaces

Tags: kotlin, gson

Consider the following classes/interfaces:

```
interface ExampleKotlinInterface {
    val name: String
}
```

```
interface ExampleKotlinInterfaceSubclass : ExampleKotlinInterface {
    override var name: String
}
```

```
abstract class ExampleKotlinImpl(@SerializedName("name") override val name: String = "zach") : ExampleKotlinInterface
```

```
class ExampleKotlinImplSubclass(override var name: String) : ExampleKotlinImpl(name), ExampleKotlinInterfaceSubclass
```

where the first interface defines a value `name` and the second interface extends this, but exposes the `name` value as a var.  I am unable to parse the `ExampleKotlinImplSubclass` with Gson because of the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.example.kotlingetterinterfaceexample.ExampleKotlinImplSubclass declares multiple JSON fields named name

    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:926)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at com.example.kotlingetterinterfaceexample.ExampleGsonParseTests.testParseObject(ExampleGsonParseTests.kt:13)
```

using this test code:

```
        val json = "{ \"name\" : \"test\" }"

        val result = Gson().fromJson(json, ExampleKotlinImplSubclass::class.java)

        assertNotNull(result)

        assertEquals("test", result.name)
```

The theory is that my superclass should not be allowed to change the value of `name`, but the subclass should be able to.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Link to sample project showing this issue: https://github.com/ZOlbrys/kotlingetterinterfaceexample

Answer (score 0):

See my Java based [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53152170/6413377). GSON does not handle this kind of situation well. The only option I see is that you do not override fields. What you could do - if it is any help - create one more level in your interfaces, something like:

```
interface ExampleKotlinInterfaceTop {
    fun getName(): String
    ...
}

interface ExampleKotlinInterface : ExampleKotlinInterfaceTop {
    val name: String
    ...
}

interface ExampleKotlinInterfaceSubclass : ExampleKotlinInterfaceTop {
    var name: String
    ...
}
```

I am not a Kotlin programmer so guess there is a lot to fix in my example code but as a principle of the possible solution.